# Как добавить горизонтальную прокрутку графика в jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Всем привет! Делаю мини-проект в jupyter, столкнулась с желанием нарисовать графики, выходящие за пределы ячейки блокнота. Вот, например, когда пытаемся вывести в ячейке 200 колонок датафрейма, то он их выводит, но как бы в окошечке со скролом (если дать команду pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 200))

А есть ли такая возможность с графиками? Вот кусок кода (библиотека matplotlib.pyplot):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 15), constrained_layout=True)
ax[0].plot(data["Close"], label="цена")
ax[0].legend(loc="upper left", fontsize=20)
```

figsize = (20, 15) - это на всю ширину ячейки. Но, если увеличить (например, figsize = (30, 15)) - то окно дальше уже не расширится, а очень хочется. Как это сделать?

З.Ы. вот пример, как jupyter делает с большим количеством колонок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот можно ли также с длинными графиками сделать?

Comment: А зачем? График же при желании можно в новом окне открыть или сохранить. Если зададите ему большую ширину и высоту он и будет большой и широкий, можете его сохранить и в любой графической программе смотреть как угодно и там уже зумить и скроллировать. 
Прокрутка имеет смысл для таблиц, но для графиков то зачем?

Comment: @CrazyElf просто это график цены актива за 10 лет, в масштабе ячейки jupyter тяжело его смотреть, хочется "растянуть" (типа как в tradingview). Иначе он его сжимает и смысла в таком графике вообще нету. Ну, только если сохранить его и открыть в сторонней программе. Но, хотелось бы без нее обойтись. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: М.б. лучше использовать plotly вместо matplotlib...?

Comment: @AlexAlex не знакома с этой библиотекой, честно говоря. Она принципиально отличается от matplotlib? Меня в принципе полностью устраивает функционал matplotlib, тут скорее вопрос не к библиотеке визуализации, а к самому jupyter. Находила где-то в интернете сложное решение этой проблемы - через CSS кастомку. Но это вообще не рационально, хочу найти способ лаконичнее)

Comment: @AlexAlex спасибо большое, посмотрела библиотеку plotly, у нее есть замечательная встроенная функция zoom.

Comment: plotly более интерактивная графика для веб, чем matplotlib.. на их сайте много примеров..

Comment: В matplotlib есть виджет `Slider` https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html